# node js express route for each user

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express. How is it possible to create a route system that renders the same page for existing users only? 
e.g user: jonh -> would have a profile page users/jonh ? but 'users/jonhhh' should not exist?

```
router.route('users/:id')
        .get(models.User.client);
```

Comment: Should /users/jonhhh 404?

Answer (score 3):

Check out if user exists and render different pages

```
app.get('/users/:id', function(req,res) {
  if (users.indexOf(req.params.id) == -1) {
    res.status(404);
    return res.send('<html><body>' +
      '<h1>User ' + req.params.id + ' not exists.</h1>' +
      '</body></html>'
    );
  }
  res.status(200);
  res.set('Content-type', 'text/html');
  res.send('<html><body>' +
    '<h1>Hello ' + req.params.id + '</h1>' +
    '</body></html>'
  );
});
```

here `users` is Array of existing users. You can use different approach - for example trying to find such user in database and then decide what to render.

Comment: How would you do the later part ? (match with user from database and decide what render)